# Choose DAC for audio

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, analog

I am trying to play music from a PIC microcontroller using a DAC.  I have seen other similar questions, but they use parallel interfaces and I am hoping to save pins with SPI as the interface.  I saw this chip MAX541CCPA and thought it looked good, but I don't know what specifications are important when choosing the DAC.  I figured a low settling time is probably important.  The music is stored as mono 16 bit PCM.

Comment: 1/1us = 1 MHz, crappy audio typically requires 32 kHz or greater, you'll be fine. You've sorta overspecced, but meh.

Comment: Just a couple of observations: It's only one channel - so you will need to use two, or mix stereo music into a single channel. It's plenty fast enough, but it's asynchronous - so you will need make sure you update it with the precise timing (a timer interrupt would work). Your update rate should be every 22.675 microseconds for CD audio, and can be slower for MP3. MP3 will require a variety of update rates.

Comment: If it is voltage output, can I drive a speaker directly from it without any other device?

Comment: Your DAC seems to be a bit expensive. A very good and cheap audio DAC is the AK4420ET. It also has a serial interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DAC you have chosen will work fine.  Remember that to provide output samples your SPI clock and data signals will have to run at 16 times the update rate because you have to shift the data out serially, so choose your clock speed to allow this plus some overhead to handle your interrupt service routine.  Keep the ISR small.

The output pin on the DAC has an output resistance of 6.25K, so you will need a buffer or amplifier depending on the type of speaker you will be using.